# get element from string 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a simple question. How to get one element from this 2d array:

`String s2box[][]= {{"f","3","0","d"},{"1","d","e","8"},{"8","4","7","a"},      {"e","7","b","1"},{"6","f","a","3"},{"b","2","4","f"},{"3","8","d","4"},{"4","e","1","2"},{"9","c","5","b"},{"7","0","8","6"},{"2","1","c","7"},{"d","a","6","c"},{"c","6","9","0"},{"0","9","3","5"},{"5","b","2","e"},{"a","5","f","9"}};`

I was trying like this, 
`String sboxl = s2box[2,3];`

I want to take this element for example and than convert it into binary number.

Why is this not working?

Comment: What you have is not a 2d array. its a jagged array (array of arrays).

Comment: String s2box[,] = {{...}}. The difference is in a jagged array, the rows can be of different lengths. in a 2d array, they cant.

Comment: How can I convert this one into 2d array?

Comment: String s2box[,]= {{"f","3","0","d"},{"1","d","e","8"},{"8","4","7","a"}, {"e","7","b","1"},{"6","f","a","3"},{"b","2","4","f"},{"3","8","d","4"},{"4","e","1","2"},{"9","c","5","b"},{"7","0","8","6"},{"2","1","c","7"},{"d","a","6","c"},{"c","6","9","0"},{"0","9","3","5"},{"5","b","2","e"},{"a","5","f","9"}};
I dont know enough java to tell you how to do it in general other than with for loops. as an aside, you might want to use a char[,] here, as it seems you dont really need more than one charachter.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
String sbox1 = s2box[2][3];
```

The syntax you are using is incorrect for Java.  Another way to look at it is like this:

```
String[] sboxTemp = s2box[2];
String sbox1 = sboxTemp[3];
```

Comment: Oh my God! I'm so sorry. I was tired and made mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get the element from the array and convert it to the respective binary mode you need to do this:

```
String s2box[][]= {{"f","3","0","d"},{"1","d","e","8"},{"8","4","7","a"}, {"e","7","b","1"},{"6","f","a","3"},{"b","2","4","f"},{"3","8","d","4"},{"4","e","1","2"},{"9","c","5","b"},{"7","0","8","6"},{"2","1","c","7"},{"d","a","6","c"},{"c","6","9","0"},{"0","9","3","5"},{"5","b","2","e"},{"a","5","f","9"}};
String sbox1 = s2box[2][3];
String sbox1Binary = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(sbox1, 16).intValue());
System.out.println(sbox1Binary);
```

**Output:**
1010

Comment: I have problem when I want to get some number which is different than letter, for example 0. I don't get 0000. I just get 0.

Comment: Try `System.out.printf("%04d\n", Integer.parseInt(sbox1Binary));`.

Comment: It's not about printing. It's not problem. But I want to save it in real binary format which is 4 bits when converting from hex, because I want to use it later to add binary digits using xor.